# Unrecognizability of $L(M_1) \cap L(M_2) = \emptyset$

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

Let's define a language $$C = \{ \{M_1, M_2\} \mid M_1, M_2 \text{ are TMs s.t. } L(M_1) \cap L(M_2) = \emptyset \}$$

We have to show that $C$ is unrecognizable.

I am having trouble going on about with this proof. I am trying to do this by reduction, showing that this language is unrecognizable, but I am unsure on how to reduce this problem into a simpler problem.

Comment: Turing machines cannot be unrecognizable. *Languages* can.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus so how would you recommend to show the language is unrecognizable? im taking about the language not the turing machine, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Reduce one of the standard unrecognizable languages to $C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T$ be a Turing machine. Construct a Turing machine $T'$ that simulates $T$ on the empty input word and, when (if) the simulation ends, it accepts (regardless of the input to $T'$). Notice that $T'$ can be computed from $T$.

Pick $M_2$ as the Turing machine that immediately halts and accepts.

Then $\{T', M_2\} \in C$ iff $L(T') = \emptyset$, which happens iff $T$ does not halt on the empty input word. Therefore if $C$ were recognizable, the halting problem would be decidable (since the language of all Turing machines that halt on the empty input word is recognizable).
This shows that $C$ is not recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce from the [acceptance problem](http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/6420/spr16/Notes/Computability/accept.html) using the following trick:

Let $M_w$ be the turing machine that accepts if and only if its input is $w$. Then $L(M_w)=\{w\}$.

Therefore, for any TM $M$ and word $w$,

\begin{matrix} \langle M,w\rangle \in ACCEPT_{TM} &\iff\\ w\in L(M)&\iff\\ L(M)\cap \{w\}\neq \emptyset &\iff\\ L(M)\cap L(M_w)\neq \emptyset &\iff\\ \langle M,M_w\rangle \notin C &\iff\\ \langle M, M_w\rangle \in \overline C\end{matrix}

Which means that the reduction defined by $f(\langle M,w\rangle) = \langle M, M_w \rangle$ is a reduction from the acceptence problem to $\overline C$, and thus $C$ is undecidable (since the acceptence is not in co-RE).

Comment: thank you for the response but the question is asking to show C is unrecognizable not undecidable

Comment: Yes, my bad. I fixed the answer (it is a correct reduction to the complement of $C$, not to $C$ itself)